# How did I get the "What does it mean?" achievement?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

I was in The Highlands and just got the "What does it mean?" achievement. Followed by Handsome Jack hilariously reenacting the popular "Double Rainbow" viral video in a monologue. I have NO idea what triggered this. I was in an area I had been to several times today doing quests and other randomness. What triggered me getting this achievement?

Comment: Handsome jack? The Claptrap did it in my game

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sequence is triggered on **an overlook with a tent in east of The Highlands**. It's most accessible from the cliff at the end of the Hyperion base on the east side of the map. Jump straight down to the tented overlook. Either Handsome Jack or Claptrap will imitate the [popular "Double Rainbow" clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQSNhk5ICTI) and trigger the achievement. A "double rainbow" glows in the distance:

[image: all the way across the sky]

Video walkthrough by GameFront:

Comment: Does it always happen? I failed to activate this with a friend (at night) while I DID see it with a different group (daytime)

Comment: I know I've seen it [done at night](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEwja45w1EU&hd=1&t=3m14s). It should work if you walk near the ledge.

Comment: I probably just ran off the edge too quick then