# How many challenges must be completed for "Yo Dawg I Herd You Like Challenges"?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the Challenges menu under the "Miscellaneous" category I see a challenge called "Yo Dawg I Herd You Like Challenges".  It currently shows progress 4/5 for LV 1 for me, and I don't understand where that number comes from.  I've done a lot of challenges and my Badass rank is above 500.  How many challenges must I complete to make progress on this challenge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progress on this challenge is the sum of **completed challenges**. Finishing a [Vault Symbol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84840/21177) challenge in any one level counts the same as finishing a "Level 5" challenge.

Levels 1–4: 5, 25, 50, 100 completed challenges<sup>[1](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Challenges#Miscellaneous)</sup>

Comment: Also, level 4 in this challenge requires you to complete 100.

Comment: Really? The incomplete borderlands wiki only goes up to level 2. (The game does have 112 challenges according to the wiki).

Comment: http://www.bl2wiki.com/Challenges#Miscellaneous

Comment: Ahh the other wiki. Gotta love that, having double wikis.

Comment: Two wikis to rule them all

Comment: Well Wikia is filled with "Look At The Gun I Found" people. So I hope the second one goes better.