# Frostburn Canyon collectibles

Tags: borderlands-2

I know where the [vault symbols](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84840/21177) are, but I can't find the rest of the collectibles. Where are the three chronicles of the Firehawk, and the hanging totems? Also, I already finished the main mission in this area and I thought all of the totems were ignited en route—did I miss something or catch a co-op bug? Are there different totems? Did I need to ignite them personally? Can I redo that portion of the mission?

#### Burning Senstation

> Find Incinerator Clayton's chronicles of the Firehawk. (3)

#### Totems of Fire

> Ignite all the hanging totems. (10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hanging totems hand all around Frostburn Canyon, and look like this (ignited)

[image: Ignited hanging totem]

Below is the map of all ten hanging totems, as well as three chronicles of the Firehawk, with a suggested collection routes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Hanging Totems" are made of wood with a skull in the center and generally hang over main walkways. They're spread all over the map. They aren't the totems you ignite during the Firehawk mission (hanging is the key word).  They don't have to be ignited all in one run, and they're not part of a mission so you can do them at any time. Shoot one with a fire weapon and it should light up and a pop up will show your challenge progress.

You have to ignite them manually with a fire weapon, and a friend igniting them doesn't count for you. I don't know the exact location, but you'll have to cover most of the whole map and look up for the totems.

I'm afraid I never found the Chronicles of the Firehawk so I have no idea where to get those.