# Getting to Terramorphous Peak Cult of the Vault symbol?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been trying to get to the Cult of the Vault symbol that's "under the platform you drop down from to enter the arena with Terramorphous" (description taken from [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84840/where-are-all-of-the-hidden-vault-symbols-for-the-cult-of-the-vault-challenges) question), and have found some [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK98d8J9ryA) showing how to get to them if you have a friend in your game. However, I mostly play alone, so the trick shown in the video isn't really an option for me.

I've tried to get Terramorphous or his tentacles to knock me up to the symbol, but haven't had any success so far. Has anyone ever got to the symbol while playing solo, and if so how? Does a reliable method of getting knocked up to the symbol by Terramorphous even exist?

Edit 12/25: I'm playing on the PC, so I also don't have the option of using a guest player in splitscreen to reproduce the trick shown in the video.

Comment: Does the grate above the hole to Terra stay closed before you jump down in single player? I got it by glitching through the wall when the grate was closed, but I don't know if you can ever stand on the grate in solo mode.

Comment: The grate does stay closed briefly before it drops you down, maybe for a couple of seconds. Did you glitch through the wall by running at it while standing on the grate or something?

Comment: You're supposed to get that by standing directly above him when he pops up anytime. But even though this is the intended way, it's still extremely hard and unreliable since most of the time, he doesn't knock you hard enough up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing on a platform that supports splitscreen, this can easily be solo'd by jumping down with your guest first, and then jumping down with your main character just before the gates close, look up and discover the symbol.

Comment: He said solo, not multiplayer/splitscreen. And if you're on a PC, like the majority of BL2 players, you can't use splitscreen.

Comment: I'll update my answer to specify console version since the question is not platform specific, it could be useful to those players.

Comment: I take back what I said about consoles (I was wrong).

Comment: Sorry, should have specified I was playing on PC. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Fair enough Kotsu I got rid of that link. The answer is for those whose version supports splitscreen, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

While I tried getting this with a friend the trick I did *should* work with one player as long as you can land on the fully-closed track.

All I did was run or jump into the wall repeatedly before/while the grate was falling open. After several attempts (I was actually just trying to jump *after* the grate opened or before it closed) I managed to glitch through the wall and briefly got access to the vault symbol. It's not very reliable, but I've heard of others getting the symbol this way and if anything it seems no less difficult than doing it the normal way with two people.

Comment: I tried doing this for quite a while today, with no luck. Is there any specific section of the wall you were jumping into in order to glitch through it?

Comment: @Jonas it was right in the middle, between the two "flaps". however the door might have been partially opened when I landed on it or something, I was *trying* to do the 2 player trick, but the door closed too early.

Answer (score -4):

Use Terramorphous to launch yourself to it.

Comment: It says in the question that they have tried that and can't get it to work.